# QtCreator - use static dll lib

Tags: c++, static-libraries, qt-creator

I want to make my app without any dependancies for the users. It works well when I put the dll files into the same folder as my exe.
I'm trying to set all those libraries to static use the following code in my pro file (Qt 4.8.1):

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc
CONFIG += static
```

The previous code doesn't change anything.

Here are the dll file I have included into my project folder:

- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
- mingwm10.dll
- QtCore4.dll
- QtGui4.dll

The fact is I don't want my app be more than a file and I don't want the users to download libs files, which are heavy (9mB for the last one).

Is there a way to compile a Qt project and use static libs?

I've tried to read some tutorials I've found on the Internet but they are all outdated. For what I read too, the solution would be to rebuild the Qt source code staticaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to fully statically compile against Qt you need to rebuild the framework as static, using the pre-compiled framework isn't enough - unless you have a commercial license and can get the static binaries.

See: http://www.formortals.com/how-to-statically-link-qt-4/, http://www.formortals.com/build-qt-static-small-microsoft-intel-gcc-compiler/ and http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment.html#static-vs-shared-libraries for more information.

Comment: I've compiled the framework. All seems to be done. But what am I supposed to do next? Do I have to copy/paste something?

Comment: In your QMake project file you should be able to link against the static framework by including `CONFIG += static` and including the `LIBS` links to the Qt framework.

Answer (score 0):

Download already compiled libraries. If you are building against a platform, use cross-compiled libraries of that. You can link those libraries in Makefile statically [in #INCLUDE and LIBS variable in makefile]. The only drawback is your exe size will be increased.

Comment: I've googled that but I don't know what I'm supposed to do. I've already added the following line into my pro file: `LIBS        =        -L"c:\PATH\TO\LIB" -lmingw32 -lQtGui4 -lQtCore4`. But I don't know the name of the `libgcc_s_dw2` lib nor where to find those files. Thanks.

Comment: check for library with .a extensions and add those to your LIBS.

Comment: I've found two lib (libQtGui4.a and libQtCore4.a) into the directory `mingw\lib\` of Qt. I've added the following lines into my pro file: `LIBS += -lQtGui4
LIBS += -lQtCore4
`
But it still asks me for those dll...